# float32 representation to float64 NumPy Python

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point

**Situation**

- I need to read data from a file using `fits` from [`astropy.io`](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/io/fits/), which uses in [`numpy`](http://www.numpy.org/).
- Some of the values I get when reading are very small negative [`float32`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.types.html) numbers, when there actually shouldn't exist negative values on the data (because of the data characteristics).

**Questions**

- Can it be that those numbers were very small `float64`, that when read and casted to `float32` became negative? If yes, how small do they have to be?
- Is there a way to rewind the process, i.e., to get the original positive very small `float64` value?

Comment: Most likely, the error was introduced at some point before the file was written, not when the file was read.

Comment: @user2357112 Either way, lets suppose they were casted into `float32` when written and not then read. Could I get the original `float64` value back from the `float32`, knowing that it should be an extremely small value?

Comment: No, and neither cast would change a number's sign anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - Can it be that those numbers were very small float64, that when read and casted to float32 became negative? If yes, how small do they have to be?

No - if the original float64 value was smaller than the smallest representable float32 number then it would simply be equal to zero after casting:

```
tiny = np.finfo(np.float64).tiny    # smallest representable float64 value
print(tiny)
# 2.22507385851e-308
print(tiny == 0)
# False
print(np.float32(tiny))
# 0.0
print(np.float32(tiny) == 0)
# True
```

Casting from one signed representation to another always preserves the [sign bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_bit).

> - Is there a way to rewind the process, i.e., to get the original positive very small float64 value?

No - casting down from 64 to 32 bit means you are effectively throwing away half of the information in the original representation, and once it's gone there's no magic way to recover it.

A much more plausible explanation for the negative values is that they result from rounding errors on calculations performed on the data before it was stored.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation :)